# tkinter: lambda multiple Buttons to a Label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lambda

Description: I would like to be able to click a button and have it send it's value to the label widget which is (`lab_1`), I understand to do one single button you have to use `command=lambda: lab_1.configure(text=0)` but how would you go about printing values to the label when I have used a `for` loop to create all of my buttons in an embedded list. as of right now all of the buttons have the variable named `key_press`.

Simplified Questions:

- How do you write all the values to my label (`lab_1`)?
- How can you use a `for` loop so every time that button is clicked it will display its value to the `Label`?

---

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
# Change the original tkinter icon
root.iconbitmap('C:\\Users\\bmxfi\Downloads\images.ico')
# Set the title of the window
root.title('Calculator')
# Change the geometry of the window
root.geometry('300x450+750+150')
# Setting Minimum and Maximum window width and height
root.minsize(width=300, height=450)
root.maxsize(width=300, height=450)
# Create Rows and Columns to display widgets
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=100)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=100)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=100)
# Columns start here:
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=100)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=100)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=100)
# Configuring the Main window named: root
root.configure(bg='#353535')
# Creating the main label that will display the calculated results
lab_1 = tk.Label(root, width=40)
lab_1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='we')
lab_1.configure(bg='#545454', font=('Computer Modern', 25, 'bold'),
                fg='White', justify='right')
# Main Calculator Layout
# List Box for a calculator layout
box_1 = tk.Listbox(root)
box_1.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=2)
box_1.configure(bg='#353535', relief='flat')
# Button Layout
calculator_layout = [[(7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1), ('(', 1), (')', 1)],
                     [(4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), ('×', 1), ('÷', 1)],
                     [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), ('+', 1), ('-', 1)],
                     [(0, 1), ('±', 1), ('.', 1), ('-', 1), ('=', 1)]]

# Iterating through my list to get a set of buttons
row = 0
for i in calculator_layout:
    col = 0
    for a in i:
        key_press = tk.Button(box_1, text=a[0])
        key_press.grid(row=row, column=col, ipadx=10, ipady=8, sticky='we')
        key_press.configure(background='#545454', fg='white',
                            font=('Computer Modern', 10),
                            activebackground='red', state='normal')
        col += a[1]
    row += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by giving the `lambda` each `Button` an argument with a default value. There's no need for any extra `for` loops doing it this way (it's done in the one that creates the `Buttons`).

How to do that is shown below in the spot with the `# CHANGED` comment. The rest of the code in each `lambda` function defined each re-configures the `text` option of the `Label` named `lab_1` by calling its `configure()` method and passing it the current contents of the `text` option with the symbol of the associated `Button` appended to it.

```
...

# Iterating through my list to get a set of buttons
row = 0
for i in calculator_layout:
    col = 0
    for a in i:
        key_press = tk.Button(box_1, text=a[0])
        key_press.grid(row=row, column=col, ipadx=10, ipady=8, sticky='we')
        key_press.configure(background='#545454', fg='white',
                            font=('Computer Modern', 10),
                            activebackground='red', state='normal',
                            # CHANGED.
                            command=lambda sym=str(a[0]):
                                lab_1.configure(text=lab_1.cget('text')+sym))
        col += a[1]
    row += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much  I have been struggling for days with this.

Comment: @Braiden: That's good to hear. Doing something like this sometimes called the "[extra arguments trick](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/extra-args.html)" and is useful in several different situations such as yours when dealing with `tkinter`.